# Why is Healthsites.io API call failing?

Tags: python, api, openstreetmap, core-api

I am trying to make a call to healthsites.io to obtain sites in a given area. But so far my API calls have been failing, despite using the format listed under 'Source Code' on https://healthsites.io/api/docs/ for python calls. When I use the following function:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import requests
import json
import coreapi

def getHealthcare(APIkey):


    # Initialize a client & load the schema document
    client = coreapi.Client()
    schema = client.get("https://healthsites.io/api/docs/")

    # Interact with the API endpoint
    action = ["api", "v2 &gt; facilities &gt; list"]
    params = {
        "api-key": APIkey,
        "page": 1
        #"country": ...,
        #"extent": ,
        #"output": ...,
        #"from": ...,
        #"to": ...,
        #"flat-properties": ...,
        #"tag-format": ...,
        }
    
    result = client.action(schema, action, params=params)

    df = pd.json_normalize(result) # normalize json file into pandas
    if not df.empty: # If there ARE results, continue
        return df

print(getHealthcare('INSERT API HERE'))
```

I get the following error/traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\coreapi\client.py", line 34, in _lookup_link
    node = node[key]

  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\itypes.py", line 115, in __getitem__
    return self._data[key]

KeyError: 'v2 &gt; facilities &gt; list'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\asset-mappr\AssetMappr\database\National\getHealthsites.py", line 44, in <module>
    print(getHealthcare('INSERT API HERE'))

  File "C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\asset-mappr\AssetMappr\database\National\getHealthsites.py", line 38, in getHealthcare
    result = client.action(schema, action, params=params)

  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\coreapi\client.py", line 163, in action
    link, link_ancestors = _lookup_link(document, keys)

  File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\coreapi\client.py", line 38, in _lookup_link
    raise exceptions.LinkLookupError(msg % (index_string, repr(key).strip('u')))

LinkLookupError: Index ['api']['v2 &gt; facilities &gt; list'] did not reference a link. Key 'v2 &gt; facilities &gt; list' was not found.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think this is most likely a typo in the documentation. Probably someone wrote `&gt;` *in the code used to create the web page*, believing that it would be necessary in order to avoid `<` and `>` characters being interpreted as HTML tags, and not realizing that the rest of the code would do such escaping. Try using `>` everywhere that the documentation says `&gt;`. If that works, [contact](https://healthsites.io/contact/) them to report the issue in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [coreapi documentation](https://core-api.github.io/python-client/), I think you want something like:

```
    action = ["api", "v2", "facilities", "list"]
    params = {...}
    result = client.action(schema, action, params=params)
```

If we enable debug logging, we can see that this generates what looks
like a reasonable request:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')
>>> client.action(schema, ['api', 'v2', 'facilities', 'list'], params={'api-key': 'foo', 'page': 1})
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (2): healthsites.io:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://healthsites.io:443 "GET /api/v2/facilities/?api-key=foo&page=1 HTTP/1.1" 502 None
```

Comment: Hello, it looks like this also throws an error- ErrorMessage: <Error: 502 Bad Gateway>

Comment: It does, but I don't have a valid api key, so it's hard for me to test beyond this point. It appears to result in the correct URL (see https://healthsites.io/api/docs/#api-v2-facilities-list). If you get the same behavior when using a valid key, it sounds like maybe there is a problem on the server side.